# Why `futures::channel::mpsc` can just notify one sender?

Tags: concurrency, rust, rust-tokio

I'm reading `futures-preview` 0.3 sources to find out how to do "notify any" correctly. In `mpsc::channel` (which is bounded), multiple senders may wait for a receipt (in case of full buffer).

Looking into the implementation of [`next_message`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/blob/0.3.0-alpha.9/futures-channel/src/mpsc/mod.rs#L860-L894) and [`unpark_one`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/blob/0.3.0-alpha.9/futures-channel/src/mpsc/mod.rs#L896-L914), the receiver seems to only notify one sender per one receipt.

I doubt this works in presense of [`select!`](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.9/futures/macro.select.html), because `select!` may lead to false notification. However, I couldn't produce a problem case.

Here's my attempt to confuse `mpsc`:

```toml
[package]
name = "futures-mpsc-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
futures-preview = { version = "0.3.0-alpha.9", features = ["tokio-compat"] }
tokio = "0.1.11"
```

and this:

```rust
#![feature(async_await, await_macro, futures_api, pin)]

use std::collections::HashSet;

use futures::prelude::*;

use futures::channel::mpsc::{channel, Sender};
use futures::channel::oneshot;
use futures::select;

async fn main2() {
    let channel_len = 1;
    let num_false_wait = 1000;
    let num_expected_messages = 100;

    let (mut send, mut recv) = channel(channel_len);
    // One extra capacity per sender. Fill the extras.
    await!(send.send(-2)).unwrap();

    // Fill buffers
    for _ in 0..channel_len {
        await!(send.send(-1)).unwrap();
    }

    // False waits. Should resolve and produce false waiters.
    for _ in 0..num_false_wait {
        await!(false_wait(&send));
    }

    // True messages.
    {
        let mut send = send.clone();
        await!(send.send(-2)).unwrap();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            for i in 0..num_expected_messages {
                await!(send.send(i)).unwrap();
            }
            Ok(())
        }.boxed().compat());
    }

    // Drain receiver until all true messages are received.
    let mut expects = (0..num_expected_messages).collect::<HashSet<_>>();
    while !expects.is_empty() {
        let i = await!(recv.next()).unwrap();
        expects.remove(&i);
        eprintln!("Received: {}", i);
    }
}

// If `send` is full, it will produce false waits.
async fn false_wait(send: &Sender<i32>) {
    let (wait_send, wait_recv) = oneshot::channel();
    let mut send = send.clone();
    await!(send.send(-2)).unwrap();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut sending = send.send(-3);
        let mut fallback = future::ready(());
        select! {
            sending => {
                sending.unwrap();
            },
            fallback => {
                eprintln!("future::ready is selected");
            },
        };
        wait_send.send(()).unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }.boxed().compat());
    await!(wait_recv).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    tokio::run(async {
        await!(main2());
        Ok(())
    }.boxed().compat());
}
```

I expect this to happen:

1. The buffer is filled by `-1`. Therefore later senders are blocked.
2. There are both "true waiters" and "false waiters".
   False waiters already exited, because the other arm of `select!`
   immediately completes.
3. In each call to `await!(recv.next())`, at most *one* waiting sender is
   notified. If a false waiter is notified, no one can push to the buffer,
   even if the buffer has a vacant room.
4. If all elements are drained without true notification,
   the entire system is stuck.

Despite my expectation, the `main2` async function successfully completed. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Further investigation on the `futures` source code solved my problem. At last, I cannot confuse the mpsc in this way.

The point is that, the size of `mpsc` is flexible and can grow more than initially specified. This behavior is [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.rs/futures-preview/0.3.0-alpha.9/futures/channel/mpsc/fn.channel.html):

> The channel's capacity is equal to `buffer + num-senders`. In other words, each sender gets a guaranteed slot in the channel capacity, and on top of that there are buffer "first come, first serve" slots available to all senders.

Yes, I've first read this before experimenting, but I couldn't figure out the importance of this at that time.

### Problem with fixed buffer

Think of a typical bounded queue implementation, where the size of a queue cannot grow more than initially specified. The spec is this:

- When the queue is empty, receivers block.
- When the queue is full (that is, the size is hitting the bound), senders block.

In this situation, if the queue is full, **multiple senders are waiting for a single resource** (the size of the queue).

In multithread programming, this is accomplished by primitives like `notify_one`. However, in `futures`, this is fallible: unlike multithreaded programming, **the notified task doesn't necessarily make use of the resource**, because the task may already have given up acquiring the resource (due to constructions like `select!` or `Deadline`) Then the spec is simply broken (the queue isn't full, but all alive senders are blocked).

### `mpsc` is flexible

As pointed out above, **the buffer size for `futures::channel::mpsc::channel` isn't strict**. The spec is summarized as:

- When `message_queue.len() == 0`, receivers block.
- When `message_queue.len() >= buffer`, senders **may** block.
- When `message_queue.len() >= buffer + num_senders`, senders block.

Here, `num_senders` is *basically* the number of clones of `Sender`, but more than that in some cases. More precisely, `num_senders` is the number of `SenderTask`s.

So, how do we avoid resource sharing? We have additional states for that:

- Each sender (an instance of `SenderTask`) has `is_parked` boolean state.
- The channel has another queue called `parked_queue`, a queue of `Arc` references to `SenderTask`.

The channel maintains the following invariants:

- `message_queue.len() <= buffer + num_parked_senders`. Note that we don't know the value of `num_parked_senders`.
- `parked_queue.len() == min(0, message_queue.len() - buffer)`
- Each parked sender has at least one message in `parked_queue`.

This is accomplished by the following algorithm:

- For receiving,

  - it pops off a `SenderTask` from `parked_queue` and, if the sender is parked, unpark it.
- For sending,

  - It always waits for `is_parked` to be `false`. If `message_queue.len() < buffer`, as `parked_queue.len() == 0`, all senders are unparked. Therefore we can guarantee progress in this case.
  - If `is_parked` is `false`, push the message to the queue anyway.
  - After that, if `message_queue.len() <= buffer`, it needs to do nothing further.
  - if `message_queue.len() > buffer`, the sender is made unparked and pushed to `parked_queue`.

You can easily check the invariant is maintained in the algorithm above.

Surprisingly, **the senders no more wait for a shared resource**. Instead, A sender waits for its `is_parked` state. Even if the sending task is dropped before completion, it just remains in `parked_queue` for a while and doesn't block anything. How clever it is!

Answer (score 1):

> I doubt this works in presense of select!, because select! may lead to false notification.

No, You can't "confuse" a `mpsc` channel using `select!`:

`select!` does not trigger any mspc related notification, it just return the future that finishes first.

When the message queue is full it is  `await!(recv.next())` that notifies one producer that a slot into the bounded channel is now available.

In other words: there are no `true waiters` and `false waiters`:
when a channel message queue is full the producers block and await that the receiver side consumes the enqueued messages.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not convinced yet. Let me reword my assumption using "future" and "task". The sender future awaits for receiver notification if the buffer is full at the time of the sending attempt. However, notification is sent against the task, not the sender future. Usually the notification is propagated down to the sender future, but that's not always the case in presence of selection; the whole task may have even been dropped without seeing notification. Then no alive sender future can wake despite non-full buffer. There may be something wrong but I'm not sure where.

Comment: It is the receiver that notify, not the sender. It is a "sending" future that you select from: this means that there are no notifications from select in every case.
It is `Receiver::unpark_one` that notifies one sender in the queue of parked senders that a slot in the buffer is available.

Comment: I know. The receiver notifies a sender (in case of the full buffer). However, if I understand correctly, the notification goes to the sender *task*, not directly to the sender *future*. Then the sender task recursively calls `poll` that will eventually reach the sender future. But is this guaranteed that the `poll` reaches the leaf future we intend? I thought not, because if one arm of `select!` completes (`ready` in my case), the `select!` will ignore other futures (`send` in my case) even if they're waiting for something. If so, what if the notification disappears there? That's my question.

Comment: Future don't wait for something, they are to be polled: when `select!` complete the `sending` future is left in an incomplete state and in your code no one will poll it again for resolving it. the only side effect that I see it is that `-3` is not sent through the channel.

Comment: Yes, then my concern is that, after that, the buffer may be vacant (because `-3` is not sent) but no one sends an item against the channel, because other sending tasks are not notified. What prevents this bad (at least counterintuitive) situation?

Comment: Suppose the buffer is full: in this case `-3` is not sent and `select!` finishes with immediate `fallback`. At this point there are no any vacant slot in the buffer. 
All sending tasks will blocks until the receiver (look at the line `await recv.next()`) reads an item from the channel queue and unblocks one active sender (obviously not the `select!` `sending` future that at this time is dropped).

Comment: Ah, that's the point. I'm interested in how the last parenthesized sentence is guaranteed. I couldn't figure out that at a first glance on the `futures` source code. Doesn't it notify a `Waker` (task handle) that pointed to a dropped task (task structure)?

Comment: A deep study of `futures-rs` is needed to fully understand, not an easy task ... but clearly it does not works like your assumption. 
If it can help (a very coarse explanation): notify is a signal send to a Task. A Task is a manager of resources. In this case resources are `sending` and `receiver` stream/future. It is a Task that it is `notified` and there are the `sending/receiver` active futures that are polled at the right time.